# loading momentjs with requirejs causes app to hang

Tags: asp.net-mvc, requirejs, momentjs, durandal-2.0

I am trying to require momentjs in my web application.  I am using ASP.NET MVC on the server-side, and Durandal on the client-side.

```
requirejs.config({
urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
paths: {
    'text': '../Scripts/text',
    'durandal': '../Scripts/durandal',
    'plugins': '../Scripts/durandal/plugins',
    'transitions': '../Scripts/durandal/transitions',
    'moment': '../Scripts/moment'
},
noGlobal: true
```

});

and then here is my define function

```
define(['moment'], function(moment) {
    moment().format();
});
```

I am working directly off of the [Moment.js Docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/require-js/)
I can see that the moment.js script is loaded but once it gets through the define function the application is just sitting there.  If I take the define out everything works fine.

Can someone please help me figure out what I am doing incorrectly here?

I am adding a fiddle of my entire [main.js](http://jsfiddle.net/nickhalm/tYxd7/) file maybe that will help.

Comment: I can tell you that we use moment exactly as you are above (and in Durandal, of course), and it works flawlessly.  The only difference, really, is that we do _not_ have `noGlobal` set to `true`. Are you also loading moment globally, i.e. server-side in a `<script>` tag?  Check your index.chtml or index.html file.

Comment: @EricTaylor I added moment back to my bundle and I still get the same issue.  The only difference I see when I do that is that moment get's loaded 2 times.  I am adding a fiddle that contains my entire main.js file, maybe that will help.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I might not have been clear: I didn't mean for you to add it back to your bundle.  I just wanted to make sure that you were _not_ adding it globally [through a bundle].  In other words, if you are using dependency injection with require.js, then you should _not_ also load it globally.

Comment: I wonder if you're trying to use moment too early.  You're using it before `app.start()`.  I will say that we're not doing that.  Try creating another module--instance or singleton--and require moment there.  I promise that using moment--or any other framework--in Durandal, is painless.  I'm sorry you're having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I might have been misunderstanding a concept with require.js.  I changed my main.js file to NOT have a the define that returns moment and instead just added a new modules that lookes like this..

```
define(['moment'], function() {
return {
    dates: {
        getSimpleDate: getSimpleDate,
        getDateTime: getDateTime
    }
};

function getSimpleDate (date) {
        return moment(date).format('DD-MMM-YYYY');;
};

function getDateTime(date) {
    return moment(date).format('DD-MMM-YYYY H:mm:ss a');
}
});
```

That seems to be working out just fine.